# graph data structure and algorithm

Tags: c++, graph-theory

I am solving the problem: Detect cycle in a directed graph.
In this solution, when we backtrack after a recursive call, we need to mark the vertices that we have already visited as 1.
Could you tell me the reason why we need to do that?

```
bool dfs(int node, vector<int> adj[], vector<int>& vis) {
    vis[node] = 2;
    for (auto it : adj[node]) {
        if (!vis[it]) {
            if (dfs(it, adj, vis)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if (vis[it] == 2) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    vis[node] = 1;
    return false;
}
bool isCyclic(int V, vector<int> adj[]) {
    // code here
    vector<int>vis(V, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
        if (!vis[i]) {
            if (dfs(i, adj, vis)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You need to read about the depth first algorithm.  Here is a place to start https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search